# Equivalent of objects.latest() in App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

What would be the best way to get the latest inserted object using AppEngine ?
I know in Django this can be done using

```
MyObject.objects.latest()
```

in AppEngine I'd like to be able to do this

```
class MyObject(db.Model):
  time = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

# Return latest entry from MyObject.
MyObject.all().latest()
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet will be to implement a `latest()` classmethod directly on `MyObject` and call it like

```
latest = MyObject.latest()
```

Anything else would require monkeypatching the built-in `Query` class.

**Update**

I thought I'd see how ugly it would be to implement this functionality.  Here's a mixin class you can use if you really want to be able to call `MyObject.all().latest()`:

```
class LatestMixin(object):
    """A mixin for db.Model objects that will add a `latest` method to the
    `Query` object returned by cls.all(). Requires that the ORDER_FIELD
    contain the name of the field by which to order the query to determine the
    latest object."""

    # What field do we order by?
    ORDER_FIELD = None

    @classmethod
    def all(cls):
        # Get the real query
        q = super(LatestMixin, cls).all()
        # Define our custom latest method
        def latest():
            if cls.ORDER_FIELD is None:
                raise ValueError('ORDER_FIELD must be defined')
            return q.order('-' + cls.ORDER_FIELD).get()
        # Attach it to the query
        q.latest = latest
        return q

# How to use it
class Foo(LatestMixin, db.Model):
    ORDER_FIELD = 'timestamp'
    timestamp = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

latest = Foo.all().latest()
```

Comment: Hey Will, I thought about it, but I can't call this function without initiating an object. Is there a way to call it without object init. ?

Comment: Sure you can, if you define it as a class method (using the `@classmethod` decorator).

Comment: Excellent ! You just gave me a lesson :)

Comment: I'd actually suggest doing that instead of using the goofy proof of concept mixin I just added to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

MyObject.all() returns an instance of the [Query class](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html)

Order the results by time:

```
MyObject.all().order('-time')
```

So, assuming there is at least one entry, you can get the most recent MyObject directly by:

```
MyObject.all().order('-time')[0]
```

or

```
MyObject.all().order('-time').fetch(limit=1)[0]
```

Comment: Or MyObject.all().order('-time').get()

Comment: MyObject.all().order('-time')[0] should be avoided, as it will fetch a batch of 20 entities even though you only want one.